# ls: cannot access '/dev/binder': No such file or directory in Anbox

Tags: linux, ubuntu, installation, android, emulator

I was able to install anbox in ubuntu (~18), successfully used it, but now I'm unable to do the same in latest Lubuntu (~20), what I am getting when i list the kernel modules using

```
$ ls -1 /dev/{ashmem,binder}
```

is

```
ls: cannot access '/dev/binder': No such file or directory
```

what am i missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to overcome this by doing the fallowing
clone the repo of the anbox modules

```
git clone https://github.com/anbox/anbox-modules.git
```

cd

```
cd anbox-modules
```

execute

```
./INSTALL.sh
```

set up

```
 sudo modprobe ashmem_linux
 sudo modprobe binder_linux
```

and **REBOOT**

Comment: This by far the best info I've found regarding this topic. More importantly, Anbox now works! I wish I could upvote this 100 times.

Comment: this happens in every flavour of ubuntu, i guess after the ubuntu ~18

Comment: Before proceed with Yadu's answer be sure you have got installed dkms. If dkms not yet installed you should install it: apt install dkms I did it on recent installed Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and it works.

Comment: This didn't fix it for me.

Comment: @avidreader610 Did you manage to install it in the meantime? For me it doesn't work too.

Comment: @student sadly not :((